# Why are images in react-native app not rendering after Xcode 12 update

Tags: react-native

Not sure what to even document here. I update Xcode to 12.0.1, and out of nowhere, after building and running my application, the images inside the app are not rendering, not counting the splash screen, containing an image, which are built out natively.

These images, whether they're coming from firebase storage (remotely) or whether they're icons (locally) are simply not rendering. no changes in any image code or anything, anywhere in the application. the only change was the Xcode 12 update. and also a macOS update to Catalina 10.15.7

Any ideas on whats going on? let me know If I can provide additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is a known issue with iOS 14 as you can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279).

You need to change the following file:

```
react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m
```

and add the following line:

```
- (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer 
 { 
   if (_currentFrame) { 
     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale; 
     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage; 
   } else {
     [super displayLayer:layer]; // add else statement with this line here
   }
 }
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428

Comment: how do you fix this in production? meaning I cant just modify an npm package because my npm packages aren't stored in my repo, an my builds do a fresh install on npm

Comment: @Jim I think this issue only occurs while debugging. As soon as you deploy your app to itunes this change is not necessary anymore. 
You still could create your own fork of the module, adapt the code and then install your custom npm module with `npm install --save git+https://github.com/YOUR_NAME/YOUR_REPO.git`
Btw I would appreciate an upvote ;)